# Use of uninitialized variable - the compiler is broken

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, compiler-construction

Obviously the title is somewhat [tongue in cheek](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx), but I've checked and double checked and I can't see the error in my logic.

The compiler complains that variable `parsed` might not be initialized in the return statement. I don't agree. Which of us is wrong, and why?

```
public DateTime? Test(string nextDate)
{
    DateTime parsed;

    if (nextDate != "TBC" && !DateTime.TryParse(nextDate, out parsed))
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    if (nextDate == "TBC")
        return null;

    return parsed;
}
```

Comment: Humour is subjective. You'll probably get a better response if you stick to  the problem at hand.

Comment: @adelphus thanks for the advice but I think the title describes the question fairly well. It's not supposed to be a joke. You're welcome to edit it if it offends you in some way. I got my answer already anyway.

Comment: So, it's not supposed to be a joke? Then you actually believe that a problem with your code means the compiler is broken? Personally, I don't really care, but to many, someone who assumes that a problem with their own code lies with the compiler (or OS or API or...) is a sign of a poor developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the compiler isn't broken at all.

The compiler isn't meant to be able to tell that

```
if (nextDate != "TBC")
```

and

```
if (nextDate == "TBC")
```

are mutually exclusive. It doesn't try to make any connection between the two conditions. So it can't tell that you'll *definitely* have called `DateTime.TryParse(nextDate, out parsed)` if you get as far as `return parsed;`.

Basically, the compiler follows relatively simple rules to determine definite assignment (and reachability). Simple rules are easy to reason about, easy to implement, and easy to code to.

Fortunately, you can make your code simpler *and* make it compile at the same time:

```
public DateTime? Test(string nextDate)
{
    if (nextDate == "TBC")
    {
        return null;
    }

    DateTime parsed;    
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(nextDate, out parsed))
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return parsed;
}
```

Now we're dealing with the "special case" of "TBD" in *one* place right at the start - and then we can ignore that special case for the rest of the code and call `TryParse` unconditionally, leaving `parsed` definitely-assigned.

Answer (score 3):

if `nextData == "TBC"`, your `TryParse` is not invoked, as the whole condition cannot be true anyway. Therefore `parsed` may not be initialized.

Comment: I suspect the OP's point is that if `nextData == "TBC"` then we won't *need* the value of `parsed` (because we return earlier) - but the compiler doesn't have to consider that.

Answer (score 3):

Both of you are right.

The logic for uninitialized variable checking looks at all possible control flow paths, without a deeper logic analysis. This part of the compiler does not care that `nextDate == "TBC"` and `nextDate != "TBC"` are never both true. So the compiler is right from his PoV.

You don't want to analyze the program logic too deeply in a compiler. You want simple, understandable rules. In complicated cases the compiler would need to basically run your whole program with all possible input values at compiletime to determine if a variable is initialized.

And you're right because you know that the conditions will work out, so that the use of the variable will never be reached if it wasn't initialized.

---

I'd rewrite your function like this:

```
public DateTime? Test(string nextDate)
{
    DateTime parsed;

    if (nextDate == "TBC" )
       return null;

    if(!DateTime.TryParse(nextDate, out parsed))
      throw new Exception();

    return parsed;  
}
```

But since you're throwing an exception anyways, you might want to use `Parse` instead of `TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

as out is part of if statement you must need to inialize the value.

Because if satement go from left to right and in your case `nextDate != "TBC"` get validated first and than next statement get checked.

so this is like

```
if( fist check)
{
 if(second check)
 {
 }
}
```